# Legendre/Jacobi symbol, reciprocity laws etc.

Tags: quadratic-reciprocity, legendre-symbol, jacobi-symbol

Is there a good textbook that will help me understand the motivation for defining the Legendre symbol (and it's Jacobi generalization), and applications of them to number theory? I have a math degree and I am comfortable with graduate-level texts.

Thank you.

Comment: [Apostol's book](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/IntrodAnalyticNTApostol.pdf) is the reference, even if the proofs can be hard to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best books I know for these topics is [A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387973296) by Ireland and Rosen. In particular, see Chapter $5$ on quadratic reciprocity, and for its generalisations in Chapter 9, on cubic and biquadratic reciprocity.